# Effects of altitude on constant relative humidity maintained by aqueous glycerin solutions

Tags: physical-chemistry, humidity

ASTM D5032-19 describes how to generate and maintain a constant humidity by means of aquesous glycerine solutions. The procedure allows for the relative humidity to be calculated from the mass of the glycerine and the mass of the water in the solutioI am located in Johannesburg South Africa at around 2000m and in practice the measured humidity is slightly less (but outside of my uncertainty of measurement) than the calculated value.

Is my altitude affecting the value of the relative humidity.  If so, is there a way of calculating the relative humidity by including the local air pressure with the two mass values?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  Can you [edit] your question to describe the setup you're talking about?  Not everybody has access to the ASTM document you refer to, but if we had a diagram or a description of what you're doing it'll make it more likely we'll be able to help.